# How to get rid of pagination of jQuery Data Table plug-in?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I remove the **pagination** and **show** features of a jQuery [Data Table](http://datatables.net/) ? I only want the searching and sorting features of it and want to get rid the other features. Is there any way?

Comment: have you looked through their api? http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Comment: also here http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

Comment: I looked at these but could not see anything to completely get rid of the pagination and show features. Do you see? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: are you using jQuery UI Theeme?

Comment: yes, I am using jQuery UI Theeme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this if you are using without jQuery UI themes

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "sDom": 'frt' // only show search.. processing.. and table
    });
});
```

http://live.datatables.net/iqewoh/2/edit#preview

with jQuery UI Theme

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "sDom": '<"H"f>rt' // only show search.. processing.. and table
    });
});
```

<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip> == In header put `lfr`.. table .. then footer put `ip`

> The following options are allowed:
>
> 'l' - Length changing
>
> 'f' - Filtering input
>
> 't' - The table!
>
> 'i' - Information
>
> 'p' - Pagination
>
> 'r' - pRocessing
>
> The following constants are allowed:
> 'H' - jQueryUI theme "header" classes ('fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix')
>
> 'F' - jQueryUI theme "footer" classes ('fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix')
>
> The following syntax is expected:
> '<' and '>' - div elements
>
> '<"class" and '>' - div with a class
>
> '<"#id" and '>' - div with an ID
>
> Default:   lfrtip (when bJQueryUI is false) or <"H"lfr>t<"F"ip> (when bJQueryUI is true)

Answer (score 5):

The `sDom` option doesn't specifically control pagination.  In other words, even with sDom specified, only the first "page" of data is displayed, although all the pagination controls are hidden.

A better way to do this, at least with 1.9x version of DataTables is to specify the `bPaginate` option.

```
$(element).dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false
});
```

This will prevent pagination and will hide pagination controls.

Comment: Yes, this is why `bPaginate`, `bLengthChange` etc at all exists = a better answer.